# Saving huge arraylist, index, and other primitives

Tags: android, save, bundle

I have a quiz app that shuffles everytime it is run. What is the most elegant way of saving a game state locally so that my user can resume the quiz using the same ordered list as before, as well as other primitives such as score, level, life points, etc.

I already have a bundle that saves this state when the game is paused. How can I retain the state when my activity is destroyed.

I know of shared preferences, but there must be something more elegant?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to understand firstly that there is several possibilities to save data in your app (with possibility to re-enter application and restore data):

1) Save on disc (it fast, but you can erase this data, for example, when reinstall application)
2) Save on remote disc (it slow, but it will keep your game progress throug removing and reinstalling app).

So first of all you need to choose one of this possibilities. I think in your case it will be enough to keep changes locally on disc (besides remote storage cost some additional $$)

In first possibility there are several variants to implement it:
- through shared preferences
- through saving in file (internal storage)
- through saving in file (external storage)
- through keeping data in database

I think last variant is not for you, since you want to just save state of game.
And 'external storage' variant is not for you, too, because game state is private data of your application.

So you need to choose between shared preferences and internal storrage.
In this dilemma, you can think about what you like more. For me shared preferences provides convenient and async way to save data, which is more preferable in game. But you need to think about how many data you want to keep.

If it's not big, choose Shared preferences. And if you do enance your way to save in SharedPreferences (write less code and make it more readable), you can import Gson or Jackson library. Then pick out special GameState class for your game and just convert it to json string and save. Same for restoring. Pick string from prefs and parse it to GameState. That's all.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a database and a cursor for retrieving the huge data list. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

SQLite is very fast and not hard to implement.